# Handlebars js. #if условие не работает

Tags: javascript, if, условия, handlebars

От моего бэкенда получаю такой json:

```
{
"news": [{
        "id": 1,
        "header": "Заголовок 1",
        "body": "Текст новости 1",
        "group_id": 1,
        "date": "02-10-2007"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "header": "Заголовок 2",
        "body": "Текст новости 2",
        "group_id": 1,
        "date": "08-10-2013"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "header": "Заголовок 3",
        "body": "Текст новости 3,
        "group_id": 1,
        "date": "22-12-2012"
    }
],
"weather": {
    "temperature": 4.7,
    "humidity": 86,
    "pressure": 758.1
}}
```

Далее вывожу эти данные в мой шаблон Handlebars. Всё отлично выводится, если все данные приходят. Но может быть такое, что поле новостей будет пустым(null). Поэтому я дописал условие if в шаблон. Все блоки на странице грузятся из одного шаблона:

```
{{#weather}}
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <div class="card-box tilebox-two tilebox-pink">
            <i class="mdi mdi-thermometer-lines pull-right text-dark"></i>
            <h6 class="text-pink text-uppercase m-b-15 m-t-10">Температура, 
°C</h6>
            <h2 class="m-b-10"><span data-plugin="counterup">{{temperature}} 
</span></h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <div class="card-box tilebox-two tilebox-primary">
            <i class="ion-ionic ion-waterdrop pull-right text-dark"></i>
            <h6 class="text-primary text-uppercase m-b-15 m-t-10">Влажность, 
%</h6>
            <h2 class="m-b-10"><span data-plugin="counterup">{{humidity}} 
</span></h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <div class="card-box tilebox-two tilebox-info">
            <i class="mdi mdi-speedometer pull-right text-dark"></i>
            <h6 class="text-info text-uppercase m-b-15 m-t-10">Давление, 
<span class="text-lowercase"> мм рт.ст.</span></h6>
            <h2 class="m-b-10"><span data-plugin="counterup">{{pressure}} 
</span></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{/weather}}
{{#if news}}
{{#news}}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card-box">
                <h4 class="header-title m-t-0 m-b-20">Новости</h4>
                {{#.}}
                    <div class="media latest-post-item">
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h5 class="h5 font-600 m-b-5"><span>{{header}} 
 </span></h5>
                            <p class="font-13 text-muted">{{date}}</p>
                            <p class="m-b-0">{{body}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {{/.}}
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/news}}
{{else}}
no data
{{/if}}
```

Но почему-то в моём коде это условие не работает, всё равно рендерится пустой белый блок с заголовком "Новости", который я не хочу, чтоб рендерился. И условие else не срабатывает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Версия Handlebars v4.3.1. Знаю, что можно вынести каждый блок в отдельный шаблон и рендерить по-отдельности. Но собственно потому я и выбрал Handlebars, что он позволяет использовать условия. Хочется разобраться сначала в этой проблеме прежде, чем переписывать код под отдельную загрузку блоков. Может, кто-то сталкивался с подобным?
Вставку шаблона на страницу делаю так:

```
var output = Handlebars.compile(html), render = output(view); 
resolve($('#app').html(render));
```

При тестировании моего кода на [Try Handlebars.js](http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/) всё работает.
Подключённые на странице скрипты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При отсутствии новостей у вас скорее всего свойство `news` равняется пустому массиву, т.е. `"news":[]`. А пустой массив это `true` значение для `if`.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, благодарю за помощь. В моём случае это был не пустой массив `[]`, а `[null]`. Моя вина - сам при получении данных обернул их в `[]` по запарке. Но ваша подсказка натолкнула меня на правильный путь. Ещё раз спасибо.